# MySQL- Select at least n rows per group

Tags: mysql, select, greatest-n-per-group

Suppose you have

```
id   /   value
1        2
1        3
1        6
2        3
3        1 
3        3
3        6
```

And I want to retrieve at least n rows per id group, let's say n = 4. In addition, it would help if a counter is added as a column. So the results should be like:

```
counter /  id   /  value
1          1       2
2          1       3
3          1       6
4          null    null
1          2       3
2          null    null
3          null    null
4          null    null
1          3       1
2          3       3
3          3       6
4          null    null
```

regards

Comment: What have you tried already ? what type of data are the columns defined as; what do you want to happen if there are less than *n* in the set ?

Comment: @RussC The example data shows what he wants: In the case of insufficient data, he wants nulls. Also, the column datatypes are irrelevant. If you have a solution, post it.

Comment: I suspect this may be more suited to one's application code: any particular reason it need be done at the database?

Comment: Also, why is `id=NULL` where data didn't previously exist?  Surely only `value` should be `NULL` or else how can one relate the `NULL` row with a particular "group"?  See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea217/1/0

Comment: @eggyal maybe he just wants 4 rows per group and want the id to be null too if there isn't enough rows. I don't think that's so odd. He may have a report to write that humans will read, so it may make sense

Comment: @Bohemian: Very well (although I still think it extremely odd: if it's a matter of presentation, it really doesn't belong in the database layer). http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea217/5/0

Comment: @Bohemian Right back atcha there. I didn't post a solution because I didn't feel that the question gave me enough information to post a solution that would benefit either the OP or any future visitor.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the combination of `id` and `value` is unique. Here's how you can do it without using MySQL variables:

```
SELECT
    a.n AS counter, 
    b.id, 
    b.value
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            aa.n, 
            bb.id
        FROM
            (
                SELECT 1 AS n UNION ALL
                SELECT 2 AS n UNION ALL
                SELECT 3 AS n UNION ALL
                SELECT 4 AS n
            ) aa
        CROSS JOIN 
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT id
                FROM tbl
            ) bb
    ) a
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT aa.id, aa.value, COUNT(*) AS rank
        FROM tbl aa
        LEFT JOIN tbl bb ON aa.id = bb.id AND aa.value >= bb.value
        GROUP BY aa.id, aa.value
    ) b ON a.id = b.id AND a.n = b.rank
ORDER BY
    a.id, 
    a.n
```

Answer (score 0):

The next blog post describes the solution to your query:
[SQL: selecting top N records per group](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/sql-selecting-top-n-records-per-group).

It requires an additional small table of numbers, which is utilized to "iterate" the top N values per group via String Walking technique.
It uses GROUP_CONCAT as a way to overcome the fact MySQL does not support Window Functions. This also means it's not a pretty sight!

An advantage of this technique is that it does not require subqueries, and can optimally utilize an index on the table.

To complete the answer to your question, we must add an additional columns: you have requested a counter per item per group.

Here's an example using the **world** sample database, choosing top 5 largest counties per continent:

```
CREATE TABLE `tinyint_asc` (
 `value` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (value)
) ;

INSERT INTO `tinyint_asc` VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20),(21),(22),(23),(24),(25),(26),(27),(28),(29),(30),(31),(32),(33),(34),(35),(36),(37),(38),(39),(40),(41),(42),(43),(44),(45),(46),(47),(48),(49),(50),(51),(52),(53),(54),(55),(56),(57),(58),(59),(60),(61),(62),(63),(64),(65),(66),(67),(68),(69),(70),(71),(72),(73),(74),(75),(76),(77),(78),(79),(80),(81),(82),(83),(84),(85),(86),(87),(88),(89),(90),(91),(92),(93),(94),(95),(96),(97),(98),(99),(100),(101),(102),(103),(104),(105),(106),(107),(108),(109),(110),(111),(112),(113),(114),(115),(116),(117),(118),(119),(120),(121),(122),(123),(124),(125),(126),(127),(128),(129),(130),(131),(132),(133),(134),(135),(136),(137),(138),(139),(140),(141),(142),(143),(144),(145),(146),(147),(148),(149),(150),(151),(152),(153),(154),(155),(156),(157),(158),(159),(160),(161),(162),(163),(164),(165),(166),(167),(168),(169),(170),(171),(172),(173),(174),(175),(176),(177),(178),(179),(180),(181),(182),(183),(184),(185),(186),(187),(188),(189),(190),(191),(192),(193),(194),(195),(196),(197),(198),(199),(200),(201),(202),(203),(204),(205),(206),(207),(208),(209),(210),(211),(212),(213),(214),(215),(216),(217),(218),(219),(220),(221),(222),(223),(224),(225),(226),(227),(228),(229),(230),(231),(232),(233),(234),(235),(236),(237),(238),(239),(240),(241),(242),(243),(244),(245),(246),(247),(248),(249),(250),(251),(252),(253),(254),(255);

SELECT
  Continent,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
      GROUP_CONCAT(Name ORDER BY SurfaceArea DESC),
      ',', value),
    ',', -1)
    AS Name,
  CAST(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        GROUP_CONCAT(SurfaceArea ORDER BY SurfaceArea DESC),
        ',', value),
      ',', -1)
    AS DECIMAL(20,2)
    ) AS SurfaceArea,
  CAST(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        GROUP_CONCAT(Population ORDER BY SurfaceArea DESC),
        ',', value),
      ',', -1)
    AS UNSIGNED
    ) AS Population,
    tinyint_asc.value AS counter
FROM
  Country, tinyint_asc
WHERE
  tinyint_asc.value >= 1 AND tinyint_asc.value <= 5
GROUP BY
  Continent, value
;
```